# Export gerrit cmd query to csv, excel, or text

Tags: excel, gerrit

I am trying to save a JSON format from Gerrit query (via cmd line) to csv/xlsx from gerrit query? I have the query:

ssh -p 29418 uie7*@buic-scm-*.com gerrit query "project:^.my_gerrit_prject. branch:master status:merged after:2023-1-01 --patch-sets --files --comments --dependencies --all-approvals --submit-records --format=JSON

I need to be able to save the query results to excel/csv.

I tried with format=TEXT/JSON and > (output) to text.txt (file)/ json.json (text file) it doesn't work either.

I downloaded jq as well.

I want to export it to csv or xlsx ideally.

Any ideas please?

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I only require human interaction.